# cartesie product to generate all possible values from a given list

Tags: scala, bigdata

i want to modify this code to get rid of out of memory problem :

```
    case Nil => Seq(Seq.empty)
    case column :: others =>
      others.foldLeft(Seq(Seq(column.apply(size)))) {
        case (product, values) =>
          for {
            seq   <- product
            value <- values
          } yield seq :+ value
      }
  }
```

Comment: What's the size of the list you're dealing with? You mention "big data", is this somehow in a Spark context? What's the expected output from the input (as I'm not sure to get the point of this piece of code without more info on the types)?

Comment: @GaëlJ the size is 2 GB context is scala

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `foldLeft`, do a regular for-comprehension (or a loop) which does not yield anything (`Unit`) with mutable data (your wrapper `Seq`).

In this current scenario on each `foldLeft` iteration, we are creating another `Seq()` by appending `value` to `seq`.

Something like:

```scala
    case Nil => Seq(Seq.empty)
    case column :: others =>
      val lb = mutable.ListBuffer(Seq(column.apply(size)))
      for {
        value <- others
        lb += value
      } yield ()
      lb.toSeq // you might need to convert the `ListBuffer` to `Seq` I guess for compatibility
```